# Null reference exception any time I try to access an array member, referenced from another class

Tags: unity, c#

I'm not sure what's going on. The error is coming from something like that very bottom line. I feel like I've tried a million different things and I'm at a loss. Any sort of data that I try to access from one of the members of my  "dogButtonScriptArray" can be read just fine but when I try to copy it over to a local variable I get the error. 
Also btw, in the inspector, I can see clearly that each member of the array is filled correctly.

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {

public static GameControl control;

public int gold;
public DogSelectorButtonScript[] dogButtonScriptArray;
private bool[] unlockedDogsArray;

void Awake(){
    if (control == null){
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
        control = this;
    }
    else if (control != this){
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
void OnLevelWasLoaded(){
    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex == 2) {
        dogButtonScriptArray = FindObjectsOfType <DogSelectorButtonScript> ();
        bool test = dogButtonScriptArray [2].isUnlocked; // this works fine
        unlockedDogsArray [1] = test; // error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Null reference exception when happen that you have public thing that haven't initialize.in your code you should determine size of your arrays

Answer (score 5):

At no point in this code do you allocate `unlockedDogsArray`. You declare it near the top of your class, but you don't initialize it to anything, so the array is a null reference. You never do anything like `unlockedDogsArray = new bool[size]" or`unlockedDogsArray = someOtherArray` in the code you've posted.

Unless you do that elsewhere, the `unlockedDogsArray` remains null when you go to access it on the last line (`unlockedDogsArray [1] = test`) and thus you get a null reference exception.